# Why custom roms are .zip filed than made as .ftf

Tags: custom-roms, sony-xperia, zip, flashtool

I am asking about Sony Xperia devices and I dont know this suites other brands or not. The custom roms provided by the ROM cooks were `.zip` files where we need to flash the kernel and then the rom zip to install. Why the roms were not made as a `.ftf` file so that it can be flashed easily via flashtool?

Comment: `.ftf` are more suited for the older line of Xperia devices and is proprietary format, the trend with newer Sony devices is `.elf` instead. The custom ROM's you're referring to is more of a "universal generic" method, some manufacturers are free to deviate and use their own method of how its done.

Comment: Can a rom developer create custom rom using .ftf or .elf ?

Comment: .ftf / .elf are more of kernel images **specific** to Sony, IIRC, FlashTool can combine them into that image specifically for this case, there's a script lying around somewhere on Sony's OpenSource portal to do that for you.

Comment: then why they are made in .zip rather than the .ftf/.elf

Comment: Hang on, .ftf/.elf are kernel images (read that sentence above!). If you compile your own kernel, special handling is required to convert the kernel image into a .ftf/.elf. If you're talking about ROMs as a whole, that is contained in a zip, ready for flashing via CWM or TWRP. The kernel needs to be manually flashed first before flashing the ROM itself. Look at [LegacyXperia](http://legacyxperia.github.io) and follow their corresponding threads. What part of this do you not understand?

Comment: Thanks now I get it. Thanks for explaining with patience.

Comment: Can you combine that and make as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.ftf` are more suited for the older line of Xperia devices and is proprietary format, the trend with newer Sony devices is `.elf` instead.

Their layout of kernel image is non-standard, this requires a special script to run against the freshly built kernel image to convert it and add extra special markers to make it compatible for the Xperia to enable booting.

Without the markers, the flash will fail, Androxyde's Flashtool has the capability to generate the `.ftf`, `.elf` by concatenating the kernel image (usually gzipped raw flat binary) with a header called `.sin` which has some proprietary encoded binary that fixes up the bootloader's address from which to boot up under. The script can be found on Sony's Opensource [portal website](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/03/20/xperia-s-open-source-archive-released-with-building-instructions/), that contains a blog entry highlighting how to create a flashable kernel for Xperia S model.

The custom ROM's that the OP is referring to is more of a "universal generic" method, which contains the kernel and the files that composes of the ROM, that is made suitable by the likes of ClockworkMod (CWM) and TeamWin Recovery (TWRP)  to use them.

Some manufacturers are free to deviate on how their kernels are created and if necessary, applicable handling to convert it to a form suitable for flashing, such as Sony's own format, rather than using `mkbootimg` which is a more generic form of creating a flashable kernel (this combines the kernel image and auxiliary supporting files), that is compatible with most, if not, all devices with some exceptions, like Sony.

As case in point, the kernel has to flashed separately first before flashing the ROM. For others, CWM/TWRP can directly flash the newly built boot image file created via `mkbootimg` first behind the scenes then write out the files into the `/system` partition.

Comment: hey one more I have to ask, I can find all the generic .ftf files of an Xperia phone. Is this released by Sony or someone who got the update extracted it?

Comment: More than likely, yes, there's a few that comes with Flashtool buried in their respective folders. Use the wrong `ftf` for your device could result in a fine mess, so beware. Each of them are Sony model specific, for example, using Xperia Mini's ftf on a Xperia Sola model will have consequences.